# Eclipse shows strange [DEBUG], I want to disable it

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, ormlite

As per the below Code, I am getting every single details of the program as debug, which I want to get rid of.  If is taking too much time when running the Application.

How can I get those [DEBUG] disabled?

```
2012-01-24 18:47:25,305 [ERROR] SqliteDatabaseType WARNING: you seem to not be using the Xerial SQLite driver.  See ORMLite docs on SQLite: http://ormlite.com/docs/sqlite
2012-01-24 18:47:25,379 [DEBUG] DaoManager created dao for class class .......
2012-01-24 18:47:25,385 [DEBUG] DaoManager created dao for class class .......
2012-01-24 18:47:25,397 [DEBUG] DaoManager created dao for class class .......
2012-01-24 18:47:25,398 [DEBUG] DaoManager created dao for class class .......
2012-01-24 18:47:25,401 [DEBUG] DaoManager created dao for class class .......
2012-01-24 18:47:25,401 [DEBUG] DaoManager created dao for class class .......
2012-01-24 18:47:25,402 [DEBUG] DaoManager created dao for class class .......
2012-01-24 18:47:25,403 [DEBUG] DaoManager created dao for class class .......
2012-01-24 18:47:25,404 [DEBUG] DaoManager created dao for class class .......
2012-01-24 18:47:25,404 [DEBUG] DaoManager created dao for class class .......
2012-01-24 18:47:25,635 [DEBUG] StatementBuilder built statement SELECT.......
```

Comment: The application that you are running use some Log API. Check for a xml or properties file with some config of the level of logs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am getting every single details of the program as debug, which I want to get rid of.

[ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) spits out a number of log messages for debugging purposes if the log level has been set for DEBUG or TRACE.  If you are using log4j then you need to look for you `log4j.properties` file which is often (in Eclipse) in your `src/main/resources` or `src/test/resources` folders.  It could look something like:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
...
```

This says that the default logging level is `DEBUG`.  If you change it to `INFO`, it will only show information messages and above.  `ERROR` will only show errors and above.

You could turn off the ORMLite messages specifically by adding the following to your `log4j.properties` file:

```
log4j.logger.com.j256.ormlite=INFO
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But what if i'm not using log4j but those debug messages still appear? How do I get rid if them then?

Comment: Any idea what logger you _are_ using @Indrek?  If it is the local logger then see here: http://ormlite.com/docs/logging

Comment: I don't have any *.properties files in my project root and I don't have log4j added to system path nor to project build path. Creating a file `ormliteLocalLog.properties` in project root and adding a line `com\.j256\.ormlite.* = INFO` didn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure project root is the right place for that file.  Typically I put it in `src/main/resources`. It should be at the root of your classpath not project.  If you are using Android then see: http://ormlite.com/docs/android-logging

Comment: For those encountering the same issue as @IndrekKõue I've [expanded upon Gray's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68554325/885922). I had a similar problem with Spring Boot and JGit

Answer (score 1):

Expanding upon [Gray's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8994605/885922):

- The reason why you're seeing `DEBUG` is because by default/no provided configuration, the root logger which outputs to console has its logging level set to `DEBUG`. Thus dependencies with `DEBUG` logging such as ORMLite (or in my case [JGit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/)) will be logged.
- However as [Indrek has found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991657/eclipse-shows-strange-debug-i-want-to-disable-it#comment15377297_8994605), where to set the configuration can be confusing since most logging frameworks attempt to auto-configure and do so differently.
- Useful logging (auto)configuration references:

  - [Log4J Configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)
  - [Logback Auto-Configuration](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#auto_configuration)
  - [Spring Boot Custom Log Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.custom-log-configuration)

For the lazy/TLDR using Spring Boot or relying on its dependencies:

- Specify the logging level in `application.properties` (or equivalent) e.g. `logging.level.org.eclipse.jgit=INFO`
- If you're relying on its dependencies e.g. library module for Spring Boot app i.e. no `application.properties`, then try adding `logback.xml` to `src/main/resources`

Example `logback.xml`:

```xml
<configuration>
    <!-- Not necessary if specifying a logging level for a specific package -->
    <root level="info"/>
    <!-- Replace with whatever package is annoying you -->
    <logger name="org.eclipse.jgit" level="info"/>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

In you log properties file, change the level of logs and disable the debug level.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Spring caused the "problem". After removing from pom.xml (I really didn't need spring longer), tons of logs disappeared! Honestly, I don't know where to set Spring logs debug level, but it could be helpful for those who have Spring and do not know where to start search.