# How to configure JGit's logging in eclipse

Tags: logging, eclipse-plugin, logback, jgit

We are developing an Eclipse application which uses JGit in its recent version 5.10.0. This version has started producing debug-level logs as seen below. We would like to suppress this console output or even better configure it. Setting properties on the Log4j root logger has not had any effect.

So the question is:

**How do you programmatically configure JGit's logging facility from the code of an Eclipse plugin?**

Note: I have found that this behaviour occurs once the logback bundles are part of the running platform. Effectively this question translates to configuring logback. I have added dependency on the bundles and configured the root and the class-specific loggers, but neither of these methods have helped.

```
16:51:59.405 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileSnapshot - file=/tmp/git8469351980689422371/.git/modules/learn-target/config, isRacyClean=false, read=2021-03-24 16:51:58.305366000, lastModified=2021-03-24 16:51:54.906786000, delta=3398580000 ns, racy<=2500000000 ns
16:51:59.405 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileSnapshot - file=/tmp/git8469351980689422371/.git/modules/learn-target/config, is unmodified
16:51:59.405 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileSnapshot - file=/tmp/git8469351980689422371/.git/modules/learn-target/packed-refs, isRacyClean=false, read=2021-03-24 16:51:58.307501000, lastModified=2021-03-24 16:51:54.842785000, delta=3464716000 ns, racy<=2500000000 ns
```

Comment: The [recent version is 5.11](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.jgit). You might have a look how EGit does it.

Comment: @howlger 5.10.0 is the most recent bundled in 2021/03 target. So unless the difference contributes to solving this issue, this remark does not seem helpful. If you know how EGit does it, then details would also be helpful.

Comment: You can find the [source code of EGit here](https://git.eclipse.org/c/egit/egit.git/). Show your code and tell where you get stuck. In case it matters and for the sake of truth, JGit 5.10 was part of the Eclipse IDE 2020-12 release and the recent version of JGit is 5.11 contained in the [Eclipse IDE 2021-03 simultaneous release](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/2021-03).

Comment: @howlger Thank you, but the pointer to a whole project is about as helpful as telling me to 'look at the internet'. As for the version differences: Great that there is a minor increment difference. I assume this has no relevance to the question.

Comment: For those looking to squelch JGit debug logging outside of Eclipse plugin e.g. module for Spring Boot app, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68554325/885922

Answer (score 1):

As indicated, JGit uses the Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J) to produce its outputs. In Eclipse a Fragment by name `ch.qos.logback.slf4j` is loaded into the logback plugins `ch.qos.logback.*` and provides a service to output logs. Take this binding fragment or the service bundle out of your configuration, and things go quiet.

Logback [performs automatic configuration on startup](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#auto_configuration). If nothing else is set up, the basic configuration produces output at `DEBUG` level. And that may mean a lot of output.

In a normal Java setup [you can print the status of the logback configuration at any time](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#automaticStatusPrinting).

However, Eclipse-world is different. The issue at hand here is that plugins *depend* on the JGit plugin `org.eclipse.jgit`. This means before your code runs, JGit's code will run setting up. Since there is no special configuration we end up with the Debug output before we even get a foot in.

The answer is

- To configure logback using another, dedicated plugin that you are writing and,
- To make sure this plugin starts before all other plugins.

The pattern is described in excellent detail in [Martin Vogella's corresponding blog](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseLogging/article.html#exercise-slf4j-and-logback-in-eclipse-applications). Copy and paste the steps from the boilerplate there. However, I would like to explain a few more Eclipse details:

1. [Start levels start plugins in 'tiers'.](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/06/10/osgi-and-start-levels/)
2. [Plugins **are lazy by default**. To make them start automatically at the beginning, you need to use an extension point.](https://help.eclipse.org/2021-03/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_startup.html)
3. If you are developing a product, you can also [set the start level and automatic startup in a configuration file.](https://help.eclipse.org/2021-03/rtopic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/product_editor/configuration.htm)

Finally, a lot of people use Tycho and Plugin Tests in Tycho. These come up with a default target platform and application setup. To set the auto-start in Tycho use the [bundle start level specification](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#bundleStartLevel) in [Tycho's Surefire Plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html).

Now all you need is to write a new Plugin and configure it in three different places. :)